# Background Kotlin Multiplatform platform-specific

Tags: android, kotlin, jvm, kotlin-multiplatform

How do I add platform-specific background images, because if I only use one of them, it won't fit the other platform.
i used the Plattform android and jvm

```
Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.background),
                contentDescription = null
            )
    ) {
```

if i try this, the Problem is :
Cannot find a parameter with this name: painter
No value passed for parameter 'res'
Cannot find a parameter with this name: contentDescription

i'm using it right now, but it doesn't look good in android

```
Image(
            painter = painterResource("background.jpg"), 
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
        )
```